# How to write csv file into sql database with python

Tags: python, sql

I have csv file that include some information about computer as like ostype, ram, cpu value and ı have sql database that already has same information and ı want to updated  that database table with by python script. database table and csv file has uniqe "id" parameters.

```
import csv
with open("Hypersanal.csv") as csvfile:
 readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
 for row in readCSV:
  print row
```

Comment: I would suggest you look at python modules that allow you to connect to databases, such as [SQLALchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) or [Python-sql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what type of database, there will be some slight adjustments to make to the code.
For this example, I'll use [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) with the [pymysql](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) driver. To find out what the first part of the connection String should be (depends on the kind of database you want to connect to), check [SQLAlchemy Doc about Dialects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/index.html).

First, we import the necessary modules

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import create_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
```

Then, we create the connection string

```
dialect_part = "mysql+pymysql://"
# username is the usernmae we'll use to connect to the db, and password the corresponding password
# server_name is the name fo the server where the db is. It INCLUDES the port number (eg : 'localhost:9080')
# database is the name of the db on the server we'll work on
connection_string = dialect_part+username+":"+password+"@"+server_name+"/"+database
```

Some more setups needed for SQLAlchemy :

```
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine(connection_string)
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
```

Now, we have a link to the db, but need some more work before being able to do anything to it.
We create a class corresponding to the table of the db we'll hit. This class will 'autofill' according to how the table is in the db. You can also fill it manually.

```
class TableWellHit(Base):
    __table__ = Table(name_of_the_table, metadata, autoload=True)
```

Now, to be able to interact with the table, we need to create a session :

```
session = create_session(bind=engine)
```

Now, we need to begin the session, and we'll be set. 
Your code will now be used.

```
import csv
with open("Hypersanal.csv") as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in readCSV:
        # print row
        # I chose to push each value from the db one by one
        # If you're sure there won't be any duplicates for the primary key, you can put the session.begin() before the for loop
        session.begin()

        # I create an element for the db
        new_element = TableWellHit(field_in_table=row[field])
```

An example for this, imagine you have required fiels 'username' and 'password' in the table, and row contains a dictionnary containing 'user' and 'pass' as keys.
The elements will be created by : `TableWellHit(username=row['user],password=row['pass'])`

```
        # I add the element to the table
        # I choose to merge instead of add, so as to prevent duplicates, one more time
        session.merge(new_element)

        # Now, we commit our changes to the db
        # This also closes the session
        # if you put the session.begin() outside of the loop, do the same for the session.commit()
        session.commit()
```

Hope this answers your question, and if he does not, just let me know so I can correct my answer.

edit :
For MSSQL :
- Install [pymssql](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/) (`pip install pymssql`)
The `connection_string` should be of the following form, according to this [SQLAlchemy page](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pymssql) : `mssql+pymssql://<username>:<password>@<freetds_name>/?charset=utf8`

Using merge allows you to create or update a value, depending on whether or not it already exists.

Comment: hi, Thank you for answer but ı'm using mssql and ı want to update table.

Comment: @Southpaw I think I answered this issue in the edit, at the bottom of my answer